# how to tell if a certain coordinate is in a street, using OSM?

Tags: google-maps, gis, openstreetmap

I'm trying to collect data about the distance of various points in my city from the closest bus station. I've extracted the coordinates from OSM file I generated in the OSM website, by selecting an area around my city. I've managed to get the bus station coordinates out of the file, and now I want to measure distances from houses in the city. The problem is that if I just run over all the nodes I get irrelevant data. How can I check if a certain coordinate is on a street (or say, with 20m of one)? If there is another tool, that can be used globally, I won't mind switching to it.

Comment: Why is this question tagged google-maps?

Comment: @geocodezip for two reason, 1. Stack overflow suggested this is tag, and 2. I said that I won't mind switching data source, and I've figured that google maps might provide that option.

Comment: There are already similar questions on help.openstreetmap.org, for example https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/23886/determine-if-a-circle-intersect-roads and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/31274/find-out-if-a-longitudelatitude-is-a-railway-via-a-webservice-or-program. Do they solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Usuallay you would use a so called **reverse-geocoder** that uses optimized spatial datastructures to answer this question (e.g. for OSM nominatim).

Or you do it on your own and create a shape based on the roadnetwork and a GIS **"buffer" operation** that can be used to check if a given lat/lon is within a certain road shape.